# Token, Invalid Signature Key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, signalr, adal

I am trying to connect to SignalR with a bearer token using adal

I am building a react app that shall use signalr to mirror messages from a server and render different views depending on what is mirrored. When I try to connect I get a error message saying that the token is invalid and missing a signature key. I'm new to all these techs so I don't really know where I should start to debug. Any help appreciated.

```
let connectionHub = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                .withUrl('...url...', { accessTokenFactory: function(){  return AuthenticationContext.getCachedToken(AdalConfig.clientId)} })
                .build();
                connectionHub.start().then(function () {
                console.log("connected");
            }).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)});

            connectionHub.on('message',(message)=>{
                console.log(message);
            })
```

> www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The
>   signature key was not found"